# Templates classes and preprocessor directives

Tags: c++, templates, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

A template class is a *multitude* of possible classes, so I was asking me: the preprocessor directives

```
#ifndef MY_CLASS
#define MY_CLASS

template<typename T>
class My_Class
{};

#endif
```

are necessaries?

Comment: You mean "class template". A "template class" is something else.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I agree that the asker means "class template". However, it doesn't seem easy to find out what meaning "template class" has, besides being a mistaken way of writing "class template". Can you shed some light on this for me? What does "template class" mean?

Comment: @MagnusHoff: `My_Class` is a class template (note that it's a *template*). `My_Class<int>` is a template class (note that it's a *class*). It's all in the name, as William Shatner says :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes, I mean class template. Thank you for the explications!

Comment: C++11 changed the terminology from what was used in the C++03 standard in this area. The term "template class" is no longer used. The proper term nowadays is "template specialization", much to the dismay of those of us who liked the cleverness of "class template" versus "template class".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The include guards prevent repeated inclusion of the same file. You need them to prevent a translation unit that would contain the following definitions, which are illegal:

```
template <typename T> class My_Class { };
template <typename T> class My_Class { };

// Error: redefinition of ‘class Foo<T>’
```

Repeat inclusion is very easy to occur. For example, consider a case where you include `A` and `B`, and `A` already includes `B` for some undocumented reason. You may not be entitled to omit `B` from your explicit includes, but neither should `A` be required to not include it. Only by using include guards (or some equivalent mechanism) can you make such a file structure possible.

**In a nutshell:** You can have repeated *declarations*, but only one *definition* within one translation unit.

<sub>*Counter example:* The following *is* legal:</sub>

```
template <typename T> class Foo;
template <typename T> class Foo;
template <typename T> class Foo;
template <typename T> class Foo;
template <typename T> class Foo { };
int main() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

The macros are probably used as "include guards", preventing multiple-declarations errors if the header happens to be included multiple times. So yes, they are "as necessary" as for everything else: if you can be sure that the header won't ever be included multiple times you could leave them out, but on the other hand, they are not really adding to file sizes or compilation times.